# Ordering a word list

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

I *think* I've alphabetized this word list correctly, but my friends keep telling me it's not in the right order. Can you help me spot the mistake?

> divvy, dry, dues, Eden, elf, fear, knee, opt, pet, say, set, tea

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The correct order is

> Eden, divvy, dry, fear, pet, say, set, opt, knee, tea, elf, dues

because

> each word is a homophone of a number in another language.  The order above lists them numerically, from 1 to 12.
>  *(Thanks to [Arnaud Mortier](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57057/) in the comments for corrections to #2 and #10)*
>
>  1,  **eden**, Macedonian
>  2, **divi**, Latvian
>  3, **drei**, German/Dutch
>  4, **vier**, German/Dutch (or **fire**, Danish)
>  5, **pet**, Croatian/Czech
>  6, **sei**, Italian
>  7, **sept**, French
>  8, **opt**, Romanian
>  9, **ni**, Norwegian (is also 2 in Japanese)
>  10, **ti**, Norwegian/Danish
>  11, **elf**, German/Dutch
>  12, **douze**, French

Comment: #2 is rot13(gur yngivna qviv). #10 is rot13(gv).

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Thanks!  I've credited you in my edit.  #10 was a typo, but your suggestion for #2 is a much better choice.

Answer (score 6):

The correct order is

> Eden, divvy, dry, dues, elf, fear, knee, opt, pet, say, set, tea

because

> You're supposed to order the words lexicographically based on the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Also, the puzzle text specifies that there's a "the mistake", that is, one mistake.